# Text missing in Android EditTextView

Tags: android, android-edittext, field

I have done an app which will display the text from the assets folder, I used `EditText` to show the text content. While testing my app text are displaying perfectly in `HTC` wildfire whereas in `Samsung ACE`, some of the text content are missing. I really don't know what might be the reason for this...

Can anyone help me to sort it out this issue please.

EDIT:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    Intent extra = getIntent();
    selectedBook = extra.getIntExtra("selectedbook", 0);
    Log.v("selectedBook>>>>", ""+selectedBook);
    selectedSection = extra.getIntExtra("selectedsection", 0);
    Log.v("selectedSection>>>> ",""+ selectedSection );
    contentTitle = extra.getStringExtra("contenttitle");
    Log.v("contentTitle>>>> ",""+ contentTitle );

    setContentView(R.layout.page);
    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
    view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
    setTitleView();
    setTextDisplay();

    Spannable wordtoSpan = (Spannable) view.getText();


    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

}

private void setTitleView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    headingTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_txt);
    headingLbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tbutton_left);
    headingRbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tbutton_right);

    headingTitle.setText(contentTitle);
    headingRbtn.setText("Bookmark");
    headingLbtn.setText("Back");
    headingLbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    headingRbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    headingLbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            finish();
        }
    });

    headingRbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DbHelper db = new DbHelper(PageActivity.this);
            db.addNote(selectedBook, selectedSection, contentTitle, "");
            Toast.makeText(PageActivity.this, "Succesfully Bookmarked this section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private void setTextDisplay() { 

    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("" + selectedBook + ".txt"); 
        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close(); 

        synchronized(this){
            text = new String(buffer); 
            Log.v("WHOLETEXT",text);
            Log.v("WHOLETEXT",""+text.length());
            splitTxt = text.split("@abc@")[selectedSection]; 
        }

        String splitTxts[] = splitTxt.split("@xyz@");
        Log.v("SPLITTEXT",""+splitTxts.length);

        if(splitTxts.length!=1){
            for(int i=0;i<splitTxts.length;i++){
                 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                 ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
                 Log.v("Splited position", ""+i);
                 Log.v("Splited Text", splitTxts[i]);
                 tv.setText(splitTxts[i]); 
                 if(selectedBook==3&&selectedSection==16){
                     img.setImageResource(arr204_16[i]);
                 }else if(selectedBook==8&&selectedSection==7){
                     img.setImageResource(arr209_8[i]);
                 }else if(selectedBook==8&&selectedSection==9){
                     img.setImageResource(arr209_10[i]);
                 }else if(selectedBook==8&&selectedSection==10){
                     img.setImageResource(arr209_11[i]);
                 }else if(selectedBook==8&&selectedSection==12){
                     img.setImageResource(arr209_13[i]);
                 }else if(selectedBook==8&&selectedSection==14){
                     img.setImageResource(arr209_15[i]);
                 }else if(selectedBook==16&&selectedSection==13){
                     img.setImageResource(arr217_14[i]);
                 }else if(selectedBook==19&&selectedSection==0){
                     img.setImageResource(arr220_1[i]);
                 }else if(selectedBook==19&&selectedSection==17){
                     img.setImageResource(arr220_18[i]);
                 }

                 LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                 lp.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
                 img.setLayoutParams(lp);
                 layout.addView(tv);
                 layout.addView(img);

            }
        }else
         Log.v("Splited position", ""+selectedSection);
         Log.v("Splited Text", text.split("@abc@")[selectedSection]);
        view.setText(text.split("@abc@")[selectedSection]);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Should never happen!
        Log.i("Exception", "true");
    }
}

private static final int MENU_ABOUT = 1;
private static final int MENU_HELP = 2; 

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, MENU_ABOUT, 0, "Bookmarks").setIcon(R.drawable.icon_abt1);
    menu.add(0, MENU_HELP, 0, "Settings").setIcon(R.drawable.ckhelp); 
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case MENU_ABOUT:
        startActivity(new Intent(PageActivity.this, BookMarksActivity.class));
        finish();
        return true;
    case MENU_HELP:

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(PageActivity.this, YARPreferencesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent); 
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
} 

@Override
protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences pref = 

}
```

Comment: For it to be an issue, you should post code.

Comment: Wow , superb question, so we can have dream whole night to guess your code.

Comment: give marquee effect to your text view and check, because screen size is different, your text might get truncated depending on various property you have set in EditText.